# Moving form to the right bottom

Tags: css, html

I am new to HTML5 and CSS so trying different things. I have created a form:

```
<div id="form1">
    <form action="demo_form.asp" autocomplete="on" >
        Departure City
        <br><select name="mydropdown" id="departurecity">
        <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
        <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
        </select><br>
        Arrival Time 
        <br><select name="mydropdown">
        <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
        <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
        </select>
        Departure Time
        <br><select name="mydropdown">
        <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
        <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
        </select>
        Departure Date
        <br><select name="mydropdown">
        <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
        <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
        </select>
        Adult
        <br><select name="mydropdown">
        <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
        <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
        </select>
        Child
        <br><select name="mydropdown">
        <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
        <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
        </select>
        Senior
        <br><select name="mydropdown">
        <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
        <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">     
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#form1{
 border: 1px solid white;
 margin: 100px;
 width:50%;
 position: absolute;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
}
```

Right now it is in the centre of the page. I want to move it to the right bottom of the 
page. I have tried multiple things but no help. Can anyone of you tell me what should I do to attain what I want?

Comment: Your margin as an effect too :)  and width as well

Comment: just float it to right `float:right;`

Comment: Margin was the issue, I suggest using a color background to see what you did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove margin from the css

```
#form1{
border: 1px solid white;
width:50%;
position: absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

When you write the `margin:100px` it means your element will take away 100px from all four sides.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yxH6t/)

You can also reduce the width of the `#form1` to make it more right view like this

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Demo reduce width</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/yxH6t/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/eZ8M7/ if the answer is yes, then you only need to drop out the margin sentence.

```
#form1{
   border: 1px solid white;
   width:50%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
}
```